# How do I convert my Chinese name into Japanese and furigana?

Tags: kanji, names

My Chinese name is 葉志軒 and I tried a lot of ways to convert it but it seems impossible. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Furigana is most often used to inform about the pronunciation of Kanji. Could you please indicate how you pronounce 葉志軒?

Comment: 葉(ye)志(zhi)軒(xuan)  in chinese pinyin

Comment: Thanks! I'd say the closest pronunciation that can be expressed with Japanese kana might be something like: イェ  ジ  シュアン.

Answer (score 2):

葉（よう）志（し）軒（けん）

In general practice, Japanese 音読み sounds are used to describe Chinese names (音読み is similar to old Chinese pronunciation).
It is easy to read and pronounce for ordinary Japanese　people.

Some Chinese use pinyin sound and spelling.  It is widely accepted, however, it is hard to read and pronounce for ordinary Japanese people.